# How do i prove this statement about a p-subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

let $G$ be a group.

Let $H$ be a p-subgroup of $G$.

How do i prove that $|G:N_G(H)|\equiv 1 (mod p)$?

=====

To let you know my background, i have studied Dummit&Foote text until p.146.

So far, I have proved that $|\{gHg^{-1}:g\in G\}|=|G:N_G(H)|$, but don't know how to proceed further.

I know Cauchy's Theorem and Sylow's theorem. So it is okay to use these theorems..

Comment: This is not true. Take $G=H$ of order $p=2$ for example.

Comment: Do you mean $1\pmod{p}$ perhaps? For instance, if $H$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup, then $[G:N_G(H)]$ is precisely the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups, which is $\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: @Prahlad Yes right it was a typo. I'll edit it. And i know that if $H$ is a Sylow p-subgrp, then the statement holds. But i'm asking about the case when $H$ is just a p-subgrp.

Comment: @Jack I just edited. Would you check again?

Comment: This is still not true. Take $G$ to be the symmetric group on 4 points, and $H$ the subgroup fixing two points. Then $|H|=p=2$ but $N_G(H)$ has size 4 and index 6, which is not 1 mod 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that $[G:N_G(H)] \equiv 1 \pmod p$ for any $p$-subgroup $H$. Take $G = D_8$, the dihedral group of order $8$, and $H = \langle s \rangle$ the subgroup generated by a reflection. Then $H$ is not normal in $G$, so $N_G(H) \ne G$, hence $2 \mid [G : N_G(H)]$.

What is true is that $p \mid [G:H] - [N_G(H):H]$, so either $p$ divides $[N_G(H):H]$ (iff $H$ is not Sylow), or $[G:N_G(H)] \equiv 1 \pmod p$ (which occurs if $H$ is Sylow).

Comment: How do i prove that $|G:H|\equiv |N_G(H):H| (modp)$?

Comment: By proving the two cases I mentioned: either $p \mid [N_G(H):H]$, or $p \mid [G:N_G(H)] - 1$, and considering separately the cases where (i) $H$ is Sylow, (ii) $H$ is not Sylow

Comment: Could you be more specific? I know 1st,2nd,3rd Sylow Theorems, but i dunno how to prove this..

Comment: Very well: show that if $H$ is Sylow, then $p \mid [G:N_G(H)]-1$ (this is part of Sylow's 3rd Theorem). Next, show that if $H$ is not Sylow, then $p \mid [N_G(H):H]$ - this will require a fact about $p$-groups, that no proper subgroup is self-normalizing. Then, observe that $[N_G(H):H]([G:N_G(H)]-1) = [G:H] - [N_G(H):H]$, and that $p \mid ab$ iff $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$

Comment: I completely get it except for the case when $H$ is not Sylow. Why no proper subgroup is self-normalizing? Please help...

Comment: This fact characterizes nilpotent groups, and takes a little work to prove - one can again use casework depending on whether or not $H$ contains the center of $G$, and induct on $|G|$. You may find a proof in section 6.1 of Dummit and Foote