# How do i prove $|G:H|\equiv |N_G(H):H| \pmod p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Reference: [How do i prove this statement about a p-subgroup?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830692/how-do-i-prove-this-statement-about-a-p-subgroup)

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime.

Let $H$ be a p-subgroup of $G$.

How do i prove $|G:H|\equiv |N_G(H):H| \pmod p$?

Answer (score 3):

You use the orbit decomposition theorem. Let a group $G$ act on a finite set $X$; then 
$$|X|=|Fix(X)|+\sum [G:C(x)]$$ where $C(x)=\{g \in G : gx=x\}$ for every $x \in X$, and the sum is over a system of representatives of all distinct nontrivial $G$-orbits on $X$.
In this case let $H$ act on the set of left cosets of $H$, by left multiplication. Let us find the fixed set. $gH$ is fixed if for all $h \in H$ we have 
$$hgH=gH$$ which means that
$$g^{-1}hgH=H$$ so
$$g^{-1}hg\in H$$ and clearly this holds for all $h \in H$ if and only if $g \in N_G(H)$.
Now of course not all $gH$ are different, $gH=g_1H$ iff $g_1^{-1}g \in H$ so the number of fixed cosets is $[N_G(H):H]$.
So we have from orbit decomposition,

$$[G:H]=[N_G(H):H]+\sum [H:C(x)]$$ now every element in the sum is non trivial divisor of $|H|$ and thus divisible by $p$. The congruence follows.

Comment: Ok, if there some group $G$ with order $p^{r}m$ , and $|H|=p^r$ and also $|N(H)|=p^r$ then is $(m-1)$ always divisible by $p$? Also according to theorem this kind of situation not possible, but is there doesn't exist that kind of group and why?

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly true when $H$ is  Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G,$ for then $[G:N_{G}(H)] \equiv 1$ (mod $p$). Otherwise, let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ containing $H$ with $P \neq H.$ Then $[G:H] \equiv 0$ (mod $p$) and $N_{P}(H) >H$ ( there are many ways to prove the last fact). This gives sufficient information to answer the question, though I don't give all details.